# How to display modifications (e.g. for svn) of cruisecontrol.net

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, dashboard

Is it possible to display what modifications are part of the current build before the build has completed in the Web dashboard for CruiseControl.net?

I have been trying to figure out if this is possible in the status. Sometimes I am asked if certain changes are in the current build and it would be just as easy to point someone to the server report and have them check. But currently modifications are not reported until the entire build is completed.

So in the status, you would see that it successfully completed the 'multisource get source' and under that it would report the changes. My guess it would have to somehow be tied to the modifications.xls file.

This came to a head today as we were having build problems and there was a build that actually did not report a svn modification which is clearly dated earlier than the build start time. So there is no way to confirm if the change is in the build or not. There is no log file to confirm what changes were pulled or not pulled from svn.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In CruiseControl.net there is no native way to extract the modifications *during the build*. The following are options:

1. Include the `ModificationWriter` task as the first task - or at least early in the list of tasks.

   - this could then be interrogated to see the modifications that triggered the build
   - this task is normally included in the publisher section so I cannot guarantee it will work
   - you would ideally need to send the contents of the file somewhere/somehow as per the previous answer
2. There is a environment variable included in all executions `LastChangeNumber` (if memory serves correctly) this contains the hash/revision that is being built against.

   - this can be output in the build log and may help
   - we use this and I can confirm it works
   - it is empty if the build is forced manually

Post build, the build log will typically contain the modifications that triggered the build but your question relates to seeing the modifications mid build.

Answer (score 0):

CC.NET can write out the SVN modifications to a file at start build time using the

[Modification Writer Task](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Modification_Writer_Task)

What we do is read this file and send an email at build start time with the modifications. We have to read the modifications file and create the email ourselves. We do it in Nant. It accomplishes exactly what you desire.